# Running application after clickonce deployment

Tags: wpf, deployment, clickonce

I'm using `VS 2012`. After I build `WPF` client application in debug or release mode and launch it it runs. After I deploy it using `ClickOnce` deploy and run it I got the following error on startup:

**The remote server returned an error (404 not found).**

I figured out that the problem is in the `initializecomponent` method of the main xaml.cs and the following code:

```
System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/CrosswordClient;component/mainwindow.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
```

I don't understand why, looks like `XAML` is not deployed. Please help.

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was that all of my images in Resourse folder had Build Action as Content. I changed it to the Build Action of Resource and set the attribute Copy to output directory to Do not copy. I also had to change all image paths everywhere in application so that they point out to the resources in assembly. Then it worked even after the deploy.